# django and react routing integration

Tags: reactjs, django

I'm a python Django newbie, and I'm coding for a React Django app.

My question is about routing or integration of Django and React, until now I have made a view for Django to send React app (index.html) to client and set the URL for it on home page "www.domain.com/".

Client can get app in that URL and app works, but there is a problem client can just get app from home page and other URLs will show a 404 error, means client must first go to home page then go to other pages this can be lead to a problem.

For example if client when it don't have the app, and then directly type a URL that is for inside of  react routing it says error 404 , so Django dont send the app ,

do I need to put view for every page of React app ? Because i dont think it must be like this

i know Django and react routing are separate and React have its own routing because its a single page app (SPA).

I have searched in GitHub projects and find a TemplateView in Django URLs do i need to fix the problem with this ?

Thanks. i need good solution or a way for this

EDIT :

my app view.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render


def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

my app urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from .views import home_page
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),  # i have find this code in git repos 
    re_path(r'^.*$', home_page) # @Timi answer 
]
```

my project folder urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('dashboardapp.urls')),
]
```

Comment: I haven't worked with Django, so take this with a grain of salt, you could try having a wildcard route for domain.com/* and sending index.html, and then handle routing on react.

Comment: Ideally the the react frontend should be separate from the django backend

Comment: @nullptr i know its separate so i want to make them like when a request come with a url django give the react app if client dont have it in cache and if have it just open the page to that url

Comment: @nullptr if i make django give the home page to every request that would not be a problem ? Because it just give the home page to client , what will happen if client writes url to the login page ?
thanks for response.!

Comment: Can you show your nginx configuration?

Comment: @TemiTopeYankey hi , i didn't use a nginx I'm just using Django, shouldn't Django send React app to client ? or i'm mistaking this and from the start nginx must send it !?

Comment: Okay please share the urlpattern

Comment: @TemiTopeYankey sure , i have edited again and i have added them

Comment: Okay, please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle unknown URLs gracefully in Django, you can create a catch-all route in your app `urls.py` to redirect to your main view.

```py
from django.urls import re_path

from .views import home_page


urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^.*$', home_page),  # Catch-all route
]
```

This way, when you enter a URL directly into the browser, Django will serve the initial HTML containing your React app, and from there, React takes over for client-side routing. You won't need separate views for every page in your React app within Django.

Comment: @Timi hi and thanks for response the answer that you given me is working and im thanks , i have updated my app url.py and added a template view this is working too like your code ,i want to know is there any chance to say which one is better ?

Comment: Using `TemplateView` directly in your URL is cleaner since you just want to render the template. However, if you foresee the need to add more context to the view for use in your React app, this approach might limit your flexibility.

If you decide to start with the simplicity of `TemplateView` directly in your url but later find the need to incorporate more context, you can always transition to a class-based `TemplateView` or use a function based view like `home_page`. Striking a balance between simplicity and future extensibility is key in making this decision.

Comment: many thanks for response and detail you provided .